# How to implement right click with images using angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am having an example of what i want to achieve given below in plunker.As 10 changes on right click,i want an image there that should convert to some another image on right click.Please help me out with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/vTZZ5/

```
app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
        element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

made this fiddle for you: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g66y81sy/)
Are you looking for something like this??

JS should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.img1 = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png";
    $scope.img2 = "http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png";
    $scope.selected = $scope.img1;

    $scope.increment = function() {
      $scope.selected = $scope.img1;  
    };
    $scope.decrement = function() {
      $scope.selected = $scope.img2;
    };
};

app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
    element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            fn(scope, {$event:event});
        });
    });
    };
});
```

and HTML should be:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span class="action" 
      ng-click="increment()"
      ng-right-click="decrement()"><img ng-src="{{selected}}"></span>    
</div>
```

Comment: yes I wanted same thing to happen but i want the image that should be change on click is present inside ng-grid ,how can that be achieved.I am having a grid in which i am using cel template to show image in it but using this i could just bind single image that will be displayed in every row ,is there any other way using which i will be able to display multiple images on basis of some value,please help if u know.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Tiffanie_at_cat_show.jpg',
    'http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00342/114240651_cat_342943c.jpg'
  ];
  $scope.imageSrc = 1;
  $scope.toggleImage = function() {

    $scope.imageSrc == 1 ? $scope.imageSrc = 0 : $scope.imageSrc = 1;
  };

};

app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
    element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        fn(scope, {
          $event: event
        });
      });
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <image ng-src="{{images[imageSrc]}}" class="action" ng-right-click="toggleImage()" width="150px" />
</div>
```